# Very strange api throws status 404 due to several features

Tags: node.js, superagent

Well. Exists something api, and I try get file, but I get 404 status code - why?
I don't know what is, but I found several features.
If use browser and going to path for download file - always ok, him download.
But if use modules(I use `superagent`) you are get 404 status code.
Ok. I watch on headers request - I copy all headers from firefox and set up in request - anyway 404. 
I use Google chrome, and always ok! Him too download file.
I use Sphere(~anonymous browser) - 404.
I go on linux, and try again.
All browsers drop 404. `superagent` too.
And it's as far as I know work on nginx. (message "404 not found. nginx.")

I search any ideas why it happens.

I use API from bazon.cc

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why this might be happening: Cookies, User-Agent based filtering, HTTP-Referrer Header checking and so on. You should use a packet capture tool to make sure the requests are really exactly the same.

Comment: I him used.
From him i copyed all headers without 'Accept-Encoding' - superagent throws error 'Syntax error', but anyway 404. And http refer - if him not(in browser) - all ok.